# What could I possibly be?

Tags: riddle

Possibly known to all, especially to your drums 
Particularly when a police officer comes

Sultry grin, haughty glance 
Very few have ever eyed askance

Red, flowing hair my long distant cousin has 
For in the minds of children is where she is known as

Sweetest of melody, behold the wile I procure 
More trouble for you should you not resist my allure

Fall in and over, do not dismay 
Eternity with me is but a breath away

Comment: I'm not sure "For in the minds of children is where she is known as" is correct. I think something needs to come after "as", although obviously that would ruin the rhyme.

Comment: Red, flowing hair has my long-distance kin / For the minds of many children that she dwells in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> she's a siren.

Explanation:

> Her cousin is a mermaid, she sings as allure that cannot be escaped. Also, police car siren.

Comment: That's what I'd answer too...

Answer (score 2):

> A siren, particularly she' she cousin of Ariel from the tale of Andersen.

Answer (score 1):

> You are a siren.  The word has two meanings, as explained below.

Possibly known to all, especially to your drums
Particularly when a police officer comes

> A police car siren.  Drums referring to eardrums.

The rest refers to:

> The siren from Greek mythology  who sings irresistably with a female voice, luring sailors to their deaths if they don't resist her sweet song.  Children learn this myth in school.